# How to implement Remember me automation in Firefox with web driver?

Tags: webdriver

How to implement "Rememeber me" automation in Firefox with web driver? I am using web driver 2.20, Eclipse IDE, Firefox 9.0

Comment: What do you mean by Remember me automation? Add more details please.

Comment: I have LoginPage with username,Password and rememberme Checkbox. Automation of logging in by checking the rememberme checkbox, and closing the browser. If I try to login again, it asks me for the credentials.

Expecte behaviour : Login in without asking for credentials.

In IE its working fine but in Firefox the rememberme cookie gets cleared and it doesnt login.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are experiencing that is because every time you start firefox, webdriver creates a new anonymous profile with no cookies. You can make it use a particular profile, which should retain cookies.

```
File profileDir = new File("path/to/profile");
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(profileDir);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

[FirefoxProfile](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxProfile.html) has many other options, like adding extensions and all.

Comment: Have created custom profile and using the same, but it is still Clearing the cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you need a solution for firefox, but I have the below working version for Chrome. You can refer this link for a firefox solution:  [How to start Selenium RemoteWebDriver or WebDriver without clearing cookies or cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29176528/how-to-start-selenium-remotewebdriver-or-webdriver-without-clearing-cookies-or-c)

For Chrome (config): You have to set the path to user-dir which will save all the login info after you login for the first time. The next time you login again, login info from the user-dir will be taken.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "res/chromedriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("test-type");
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=D:/temp/");
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary","res/chromedriver.exe");
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY,options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Login for the first time:

```
driver.get("https://gmail.com");
//Your login script typing username password, check 'keep me signed in' and so on
```

Close the driver (do NOT quit):

```
driver.close();
```

Re-initialize the driver and navigate to the site. You should not be asked for username and password again:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
driver.get("http://gmail.com");
```

The above can be implemented for firefox using a firefox profile.